# How to toggle visibility with multiple buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-core-mvc

Lets say I have several toggle buttons. And toggle 1 and 2 will toggle the visibility of a div, whenever one or both of those buttons are active, the div will appear.

The toggles and div's are created dynamically from db records. So there will be instances when we have 3 toggles and 2 divs. For example:

toggle1 and toggle2 activates div1

toggle2 and toggle3 activates div2

I am fairly certain this is an JS problem but if it can be solved without JS then I will be happy.

Comment: What is a "toggle button"? Checkbox? A button styled with a certain class when pressed or depressed? What is the HTML structure you have?

Comment: It is basically a checkbox but styled like an on/off toggle switch.
HTML structure? It is an abomination of HTML and Razor syntax if that is what is being asked.

Comment: What did you try? Please show us some code.

Comment: Not cool, completely changing the question like that.

Comment: Yeah I know that I was not clear enough when I first wrote it and it was also inconsistent. It is totally my fault. But your answer helped me understand where my question went wrong it is description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT to match new requirements.**

You can use the "following sibling" selector to check if a button follows a checked checkbox.

```css
button {
  display: none;
}
.btn1:checked ~ #btn1,
.btn2:checked ~ #btn2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="btn1">
<input type="checkbox" class="btn1 btn2">
<input type="checkbox" class="btn2">
<button id="btn1">btn1</button>
<button id="btn2">btn2</button>
```

This is super sensitive to the HTML structure. It's easy if the checkboxes and the button are siblings, but if there's different levels, it becomes harder, or impossible. A JavaScript solution doesn't care about the structure too much:

```js
const buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button'));
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'));

function setButton(button, visible) {
  button.style.display = visible ? "inline" : "none";
}

document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  if (evt.target.matches('input[type="checkbox"]')) {
    buttons.forEach(button => {
      let selector = button.getAttribute('data-cb');
      let checkboxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
      let someChecked = checkboxes.some(e => e.checked);
      setButton(button, someChecked);
    });
  }
});
buttons.forEach(button => setButton(button, false));
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb3">
  <button data-cb="#cb1,#cb2">btn1</button>
  <button data-cb="#cb2,#cb3">btn2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That is awesome, lets see if I can use my feeble mind and comprehend and implement an scaled up version of this.

Comment: Thank you, it works splendidly.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
    .target-div {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #99f;
        margin-top: 16px;
        display: none;
    }

    input:checked ~ .target-div{
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<input class="input1" type="checkbox"> input 1
</br>
<input class="input2" type="checkbox"> input 2
<div class="target-div"></div>
```